# VF page not able to acess css from a zipped resource file

Tags: static-resources

On our SB, I modified a static resource zip file and tried to upload it back with the changes t[image]o find that the whole site is broken.
None of the vf pages are able to recognise this resource named 'EngageAssets'. Then I put back my original zip file which dint help either. As a last resort, I deployed the zip file from a connected org and that did not work.
When I look at the references to this static resource, I find nothing whereas, in the connected org(from where I deployed), I find many references.
I read some articles about problems with zipping files from Mac (am using Mac)and I downloaded winzip for mac and zipped and uploaded but that dint help me either. What puzzles me is that the deployment of this static resource from a connected org did not work.

I raised SF case but I would  appreciate if someone can help me with this urgently.

Comment: From a mac, simply highlight the files/folders you want to archive and then right click, select Compress "xyz". Never had a problem doing that.

Comment: I tried that Eric. I also tried zipping it up using rar and winzip for mac as someone had suggested it, but no luck, cannot believe that  uploading simple static resource can be an issue :(

Comment: Is the reference URL hardcoded for static resources?

Comment: Line of code referencing your SR and an image of the Static resource setup. Also check dev console for errors

Comment: Updated my question with the static resource detail page. 
<img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.EngageAssets, '/assets/images/fancybox_loading.gif')}" /> .This was working perfectly well until today morning.

Comment: I would suggest downloading the file from Salesforce and unzipping it into a folder so that you can see the structure. You very likely managed to create another top-level folder when creating the new zip file and the path to your resource would as a result look like `/somefolder/assets/images/fancybox_loading.gif`

Comment: Shalini, Do you have cache enabled for the vf page, maybe try once while creating your browser. @Mark Pond, that could be an issue. I remember I used to mess that up quite a lot.

Comment: @Markpond, you are spot on. I had actually created a folder within a folder. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Good to hear you've got it sorted! Adding the solution an answer so that you can close out the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest downloading the file from Salesforce and unzipping it into a folder so that you can see the structure.

You very likely managed to create another top-level folder when creating the new zip file and the path to your resource would as a result look like `/somefolder/assets/images/fancybox_loading.gif`

Answer (score 0):

@MarkPond's idea worked!

**What I was doing wrong**

My compressed file has 3 directories in it. JS, CSS, and Images.
I had updated my CSS, and compressed my 'Assets' folder, upload it, and everything looked broken.

**What I should've done**

Don't create that parent folder! Just highlight your three files, and compress it.
Here's a screenshot of what worked for me:

[image: Don't put your files into a parent folder]